# Authlib vs OAuthlib: Are these libraries the same?

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, authlib, oidc-provider

I am a beginner in the world of the OAuth2.0 and OpenID Protocols. I would like to implement a custom server - provider for multiple applications. So, to use it for Single Sign-On (SSO). I would like to work with python. Till now I have found four packages, for an OAuth2.0 and an OpenID Connect server implementation, in Python: pyoidc, django-oidc-provider, Django OAuth Toolkit (DOT) by OAuthlib and Authlib. I tried to read and understand pyoidc, but it was not so helpful and easy, basic things were missing. I have tried django-oidc-provider and I was really satisfied, and the whole implementation was really easy. So, after those trials, I am left with Django OAuth Toolkit (by OAuthlib) and Authlib. Has anyone tried them? Are these packages the same? Is Authlib an updated version of the OAuthlib library? The only information I know till now, is that Flask-OAuthlib is deprecated, and Authlib is was its new version.

*Every answer or advice or personal experience would be really helpful and always appreciated!

Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I concluded to work generally with **JWTs**. As before, I would like to work with a **GraphQL** API, so I am searching for solutions about JWT authentication on it. I maybe use Passport.js (passport-jwt) or something else for Python. All the libraries mentioned above possibly will be not used.

I will just redirect the user to my main application, authenticate them with JWT, and then return the JWT back to the application. In the future and after deployment, I might also implement an OAuth2.0 provider for my website. Although those packages did not really help me, I would recommend Django OAuth Toolkit (DOT) and django-oidc-provider to others. But, also I learned that django-oidc-provider only supports the implementation of a small and simple OAuth2.0 provider. Django OAuth Toolkit comes with lots of options for implementing an advanced OAuth2.0 Authentication Server (AS), including Authorization Code flow with PKCE (Proof Key with Code Exchange), which is the most secure flow. It is also scalable and has great documentation with lots of customizations if you want.

*I sent an email to the support of Authlib, and of course no one has answered to me after a week.

Comment: I've rechecked my inbox. I don't think I received your email.

Comment: @lepture still I have not received an answer. But do not worry my issue is resolved, and I have created my own OAuth authentication system with GraphQL & Node.js. Thank you for your interest though